# Retrieving Excel cell contents returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read the contents of an excel worksheet but my method keeps throwing an exception. I've tried everything to no avail but i'm sure that its a very minor detail that i'm not seeing. Could someone look at my code with a fresh pair of eyes and possibly point me out to what i'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```
 /**
 * This method sets the path to the excel file and the excel sheet as well as
 * initializing the stream
 */
 public static void setExcelFile(String path, String sheetName) {
    try {
        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(path);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
        worksheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }


 /**
 * This method reads the cell data from the excel file
 */
public static String getCellData(int rowNum, int colNum) {
    try {
        //This is what is causing my nullpointerexception according to eclipse
        row = worksheet.getRow(rowNum);
        //cell = worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum);
        cell = row.getCell(colNum);
        String cellData = cell.getStringCellValue();
        return cellData;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Lactoferrin";
    }

}


/**
 * This is how i call both methods
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ExcelUtility.setExcelFile(PATHTOTESTDATA, FILENAME);
        String cellContents = ExcelUtility.getCellData(1,0);
        System.out.println(cellContents);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: getCellData() method, line 4

Comment: `worksheet` must be null - is `sheetName` valid?

Answer (score -2):

Found it. I had saved the excel file within a package with the class files and eclipse could not find it...I do not know why. So i moved it into a folder at the root of the project and it worked.